# How can I set on hover behaviour for a MUI Button inside a ButtonGroup

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, emotion

Using MUI v5, the following code only half works. The first button is colored red (specifically, the border and text are red), however on hover, the color of the border changes to blue (the style is being inherited from the ButtonGroup which is blue by default).

How can I force the first button to keep its red (from theme.palette.error) border on hover, ideally the 'mui 5' way (ie using sx or emotion or something of this nature)?

Current behavior: the border and text of the first button are red, but the border becomes blue on hover.

Desired behavior: the border and text of the first button are always red.

Any help much appreciated :)

````
<ButtonGroup variant="outlined">
  <Button color="error">
    Again
  </Button>
  <Button>
    Good
  </Button>
</ButtonGroup>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the button group's hover class for first button and apply your desired styles in it. To style the first button in the button group, Mui uses this selector `MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)`. By using this selector's pseudo class `hover`, you can customize the styles from the wrapper div. I've [forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/groupsizescolors-material-demo-forked-wvc6g?file=/demo.js:226-701) one the MUI examples for button groups on their [docs](https://mui.com/components/button-group/) site and applied css through the `sx` prop in the box.

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    "& > *": {
      m: 1
    },
    ".MuiButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type):hover": { // class selector 
      borderColor: "red"
    }
  }}
>
  <ButtonGroup size="small" aria-label="small button group">
    <Button key="one" color="error">
      One
    </Button>
    ,<Button key="two">Two</Button>
  </ButtonGroup>
</Box>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I learned some css (or css like things) from you answer, as well as how to use those MUI Global classes.

Comment: That's great...

Answer (score 1):

After Junaid helped me with his answer, I settled on the following:

```
import {
  ButtonGroup,
  buttonGroupClasses,
  Button,
} from '@mui/material';

<ButtonGroup
  sx={{
    [`.${buttonGroupClasses.grouped}:first-child:hover`]: {
      borderColor: (theme) => theme.palette.error.dark,
    },
  }}
  variant="outlined"
>
  <Button
    color="error"
    sx={{
      width: '50%',
    }}
  >
    Again
  </Button>
  <Button sx={{ width: '50%' }}>Good</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

Notes:

1. buttonGroupClasses.grouped is just a constant for MuiButtonGroup-grouped that mui exports.
2. The computed property name is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) - I had to use it because a template literal string is an expression not an actual string.